# Limiting Access to Git Repo for New Team Members?

Tags: git, github

We have a few new team members joining our development team and I was instructed to give them access as the `members will be testing` the web applications. They `will not be contributing` yet.

My concern is that I would prefer them `not to push (even by mistake)` until they are completely afay with the application and have more coding experience behind them.

Is there a way to `limit users to only pull and not push`?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the repository under an organisation and that the repositories are not public, you should create a new team that only has read access to the repo.

If the repos are public, read-only is the default behaviour already and you do not need to do anything special other than give the new member the URI.

Info can be found on [Access Permissions here](https://help.github.com/articles/what-are-the-different-access-permissions) and [creating Teams here](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-organization-members-to-a-team)

You can [convert a User account into an Organisation account](https://help.github.com/articles/converting-a-user-into-an-organization) so that you can make Teams to control repo access levels but read through the irreversible changes that would cause before you try to convert an account.